# openRTSP file per frame timing information

Tags: h.264, rtsp, live555, openrtsp

I have IP 3 cameras that I am recording h264 video feed using RTSP/RTP. I am using openRTSP, on Ubuntu 20.04, to record the video feed using the -m option which allows me to get a h264 file/frame. The filename includes a UNIX time stamp so that should allow me to align the three cameras within a small margin of error. However, I am struggling to do this at the moment.

Is the UNIX time stamp in the filename derived from the arrival time of each RTSP
frame over the network or is the timing obtained directly from the camera (somehow) ?